# Create UDF to split row into comma delimited single Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

In sample data bellow, I want to split the row into column using UDF.

```
CREATE TABLE ##temp
([date] datetime,
    category varchar(3),
    amount money)
insert into ##temp values ('1/1/2012', 'ABC', 1000.00)
insert into ##temp values ('2/1/2012', 'DEF', 500.00)
insert into ##temp values ('2/1/2012', 'GHI', 800.00)
insert into ##temp values ('2/10/2012', 'DEF', 700.00)
insert into ##temp values ('3/1/2012', 'ABC', 1100.00);
```

i create the function below

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Splitter(@Name NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(@Name) 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
RETURN @cols
END
```

current Output

```
CatSplit
[ABC]
[DEF]
[GHI]
[DEF]
[ABC]
```

what I want is (Expected output)

```
         CatSplit
[ABC],[DEF],[GHI],[DEF],[ABC]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I don't understand the logic of your function or how you call it. Why not just select that specific column with the `for xml path`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you need function here you can do it without using function :

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(t.category ) 
              from #temp t
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).VALUE('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''
            ) AS CatSplit
```

**EDIT :** If you are using this as column name for pivoting or something else then you can define one variable & use it everywhere in the code no need to use function.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(t.category ) 
                      FROM #temp t
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).VALUE('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''
                    )
```

Comment: i need the function because it in several place in the query

Comment: @JonWay. . .  If you are doing this in multiple places, then you can define one variable & then use it in several place.

Comment: @ Yogesh Sharma YOU ARE A STAR. i didn't thing of it that way. Many thanks